# Filtered object search using allowed keys and also a search value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

as seen in my title I am facing a problem that needs a solution. I am trying to filter my object, but not only based on keys. But also based on the value of the allowed keys.

This is what I got so far:

```
    const handleSearch = (searchValue) => {
        if(searchValue !== '') {
            const allowed = ['name', 'title'];
            let list = props.search.list;

            const filtered = Object.keys(list)
              .filter((key) => allowed.includes(key))
              .reduce((obj, key) => {
                obj[key] = list[key];
                return obj;
              }, {});
            

            const filteredArray = Object.entries(filtered)


            props.search.onChange(filteredArray)
        } else {
            props.search.onChange(props.search.list)
        }
    }
```

Structure of the list object:

```
0: {name: "John', title: 'Owner'}
1: {name: "Jane", title: 'Admin'}
```

Wanted results:

Filtered array that shows the keys filtered aswell as the search value.

And I don't know where I should integrate the filtering by the values aswell. This has been giving me a headache for the past few hours. And hope someone here is experienced with these kinds of issues/logic.

Thanks for reading.

Kind regards.

Comment: please add some data, the call of the function and the result along with the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's getting the data from the database. Idk how to remake it. And it's getting called on onChange on my search input. Wanted result is it returns everything that matches those allowed keys and the value that I entered in my search input

Comment: How does `props.search.list` look like? Is it an object?

Comment: You mean the `filtered` object has to be filtered not only by the keys that are in `allowed` but also by the value of those keys? But what conditions should those values satisfy?

Comment: @re-za Yes it is an object, I edited the post to show this. And yes I want it to only filter the keys that I have allowed to filter by, and also the search value

Comment: I'm working on your code but I'm confused. Is it an object like `{name: "John', title: 'Owner'}` or an array (or list) or objects like that? Why is it called list?

Comment: @re-za Well when I print it with console.log, it says [Object object] so I'm assuming it's an object. And the list variable name is just a random name I named it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243104/discussion-between-re-za-and-infamous-hvher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleSearch = (searchValue) => {
    if (searchValue !== '') {
        const allowed = ['name', 'title'];
        const list = props.search.list;

        const filtered = list
            .filter(obj =>
                Object.keys(obj)
                    .some(k => allowed.includes(k))
            )
            .filter(obj =>
                Object.values(obj)
                    .map(v => v.toLocaleLowerCase())
                    .some(v => v.includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
            )

        props.search.onChange(filtered)
    } else {
        props.search.onChange(props.search.list)
    }
}
```

**Example**

Let's assume `props` as:

```
const props = {
    search: {
        list: [
            { name: "John", title: 'Owner' },
            { name: "Jane", title: 'Admin' },
            { name: "Reza", title: 'Owner' }
        ],
        onChange: x => console.log(x)
    },
}
```

```
handleSearch("own")

// [ { name: 'John', title: 'Owner' }, { name: 'Reza', title: 'Owner' } ]


handleSearch("jane")

// [ { name: 'Jane', title: 'Admin' } ]


handleSearch("something")

// []
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it seems to not be working whenever I search nothing comes up, and If i print the filtered it is just empty

Comment: You need to show me how your `props` or at least `props.search.list` look like. Because with the shape of `props` I show in the example above it works for me